# How to move the origin and 3d cursor position to intersection of x,y,z axis

Tags: objects

Somehow the location of the model I created has ended up in the work space above the global axis (where the x,y,z axis intersect).
How do I easily move my model using either the 3d cursor or origin position to the global axis?
I know I can move it manually but I prefer it to be exact rather than close to.
Thanks

Comment: 1) _Shift+S > "Cursor to world origin"_. - 2) _Shift+S > "Selection to Cursor"_ (with object selected).

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I will add it to my 'little black book'. I don't know why I didn't find that with a search.

Comment: @JohnArnold or `Shift+C` to get cursor to wolrd origin. Or simply select your object and press `Alt+G`

Comment: Thanks.  I will also add that to my "little black book".

Comment: Another way of moving it exact instead of manually would be to enter 0, 0, 0 in the X, Y, Z location in the object's properties in the side panel (shortcut N). And if the 3D cursor is off the world's origin, you can enter 0, 0, 0 values for it, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a summary of comments given:

First <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to World Origin* or use shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > *Selection to Cursor*. This will position the selected object's Origin to the 3D Cursor. But the shortest way is to select object and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

Another way of moving it exact instead of manually would be to enter 0, 0, 0 in the X, Y, Z location in the object's properties in the side panel (shortcut <kbd>N</kbd> > Item Tab > Location). And if the 3D cursor is off the World Origin, you can enter 0, 0, 0 values for it, too (<kbd>N</kbd> > View Tab > 3D Cursor). The manual way of entering values always helps if someone forgets all the shortcuts.

Comment: Feel free to edit in my comment, too - the manual way of entering values always helps if someone forgets all the shortcuts ;)